# AWS S3 Access via localhost works from one machine and denied from another

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-sdk

I have NodeJS app hosted an AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I need to access objects (images) on S3. I am using AWS SDK.

Everything works as expected when application is launched on the web. 
When I ran it on localhost on 1 of my PCs (part of Windows Domain Network, behind firewall) it works fine, when I try to do run the same code on the other PC (stand-alone, connected directly to internet) i get an access denied error.

The code is identical, the credentials (Key and Secret Key) are identical.

I appreciate any suggestions on how to solve this.

Comment: Since you have mentioned that everything is identical in both, you may check this for troubleshooting: (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/)[https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/]

Comment: Sorry the link was wrong in previous post: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/   - specially please check a) VPC endpoint policy and b) block public access settings

Comment: Please tell us more about the "access denied error". What element is generating this error? Is it the whole page, or is it something like an image from Amazon S3?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein. The error on access to S3.

Comment: You can test the credentials on that computer by using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). For example, run a `aws s3 ls` command to test the credentials and connectivity. The fact that you are receiving an Access Denied command suggests that connectivity is okay, but the credentials being used are not the ones you are expecting.